# Media Garden (MediaGarden Module) Error in Orchard CMS 1.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I'm running `Orchard 1.5`. I installed `Media Garden module` and I get this error:

> The assembly reference 'Downplay.Mechanics' could not be loaded for module 'MediaGarden'.

I did check to install dependent modules when I installed Media Garden, so it actually installed Origami. Then I went and found `Mechanics 0.9.0` (it installed `Origami 0.9.0`) and I installed that manually as well.

I'm still getting the error that Mechanics can't be found though. Can somebody advise as to how I can fix this or recommend another method for a video gallery? Ideally, I'd like to use flowplayer for a video gallery.

If there's a way you've set up individual pages for videos without a module that would be helpful to know too.

Thanks!

Comment: You should contact Pete Hurst about this.

Comment: Know how I can get in touch with him?

Comment: https://gallery.orchardproject.net/Package/ContactOwners/Orchard.Module.MediaGarden.Documents